# Transfer value on textbox to another textbox on a different form

Tags: vb.net

I have a value in `Form` `midPoint`, on a `Textbox`. I want that value to transfer to a `Label` in `Form` `rangeFinder` when I hit the `OK button`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Ok_Click (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    rangeFinder.Label1.Text = midPoint.Textbox1.Text
End Sub
```

Note that you may replace the form name with `Me` if you're executing this from any of the forms.

For example, if you are executing this from `midPoint` the sentence should be:

```
rangeFinder.Label1.Text = Me.Textbox1.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Off course it can be done .. Do this in your Button click event

```
rangefinder.label1.text = midpoint.textbox1.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first form is named `midPoint` and your second form is named `rangeFinder`.Suppose the text box on the form midpoint is named `midtext` and the label on the form `rangeFinder` is named `labelFind`.

So you could do this on the click event of ok button:

```
rangeFinder.labelFind.Text = midpoint.midtext.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your button **OnClick()** function:

```
rangeFinder.Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
```